# Safe and convenient generic hashing (for STL unordered set and map) idiom?

Tags: c++, templates, hash, stl

To prepare a struct to be used in an `unordered_set`, a hashing function is required.  This can either be accomplished by overloading `operator size_t()` (ew) or annoyingly making something like this:

```
namespace std
{
 template<> struct hash<MyStruct> : public unary_function<MyStruct, size_t>
 {
  size_t operator()(const MyStruct& mystruct) const
  {
   return 0; //hash here
  }
 };
}
```

Is there any way to create an interface like so:

```
struct Hashable
{
 virtual size_t hash() = 0;
};
```

And setup `std::hash` to work for any of its implementations?  I'm pretty sure templates don't work that way, so that's left me in a bind.  Is there a safe size_t idiom that could work sorta like the safe bool idiom for casting to size_t?  Or something else?  It's silly writing out a new `std::hash` specialization for every single struct when a common interface and a member function in each struct would be far more convenient.

Comment: I honestly don't see how much more convenient this is, but can certainly be done. FWIW, you don't need this base class at all (btw, *it's missing a virtual destructor!*): you can just do this for all types that have a `hash()` member, regardless of bases.

Comment: Urk... I had never dug further, but I don't like this, like at all... Why not simply requiring that a `size_t hash(T const&)` may be found by ADL ?

Comment: It can certainly be done with SFINAE and `is_base_of`, but *why*... the whole point of templates is that you can have generic code that does *not* require pointess runtime operations.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: virtual destructors are overrated. Even `std::true_type` doesn't have one, and I derive from that more often than I can remember...

Comment: [you don't need to derive from `unary_function`](http://ideone.com/p8J7Pr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually another solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct Hashable {
    size_t operator()(T const& t) { return hash_value(t); }
};

template <typename T, typename E = std::equal<T>, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
using MySet = std::unordered_set<T, Hashable<T>, E, A>;
```

Now, all you have to do is defining a free-function `hash_value` that accepts `T` or `T const&` as argument and returns a `size_t`.

**EDIT:** changed `hash` to `hash_value`, as it was in Boost.

Comment: And, if you really want to have virtual function overhead, you can have a free-standing hash that takes a `IHashable` interface and calls ->hash() on it.  One of the points of the STL is to allow high abstraction coding techniques while getting near bare-metal run time performance, and a needless virtual function overhead on each hash doesn't qualify, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Yakk: indeed, which is why it's easier to start from free-functions and then have a polymorphic interface rather than starting from the polymorphic interface ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. there's no need for a conversion operator. The requirement is for a function object (why it's not something found by ADL I have no idea). The conversion operator was simply the OP day dreaming about a possible alternative.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Right. I am afraid I got confused too.

Answer (score 3):

> a common interface and a member function in each struct would be far
>   more convenient.

It wouldn't. Instead of `std::hash` taking care of hashing, you'd now have to bother *every* interface of *every* class/struct with this detail. You'd have to constantly deal with "Some colleague of mine deleted a `Hashable`". etc. It would not be better. It would be a whole lot worse.

You could achieve it, maybe, by a partial specialization with SFINAE.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be a convenient implementation then.  I was wondering if it could be done in a non-ugly way.

Comment: @user173342 you use the words "convenient" and "ugly" in a way that is completely different from the way other people do (as an example, "ugly" was the first thing that came to mind when I saw your suggestion). You need to be specific and objective about what properties you are looking for in a solution.